# yii 1.X application log issue

Tags: php, logging, yii, amazon-ec2, ownership

i have application that is hosted on Amazon EC2 instances 
i log my application using Yii 1.X Logger like this

`Yii::log("Something i Log Here...", "info");`

aaand , as we all know , i log my files into 
`WEBROOT/protected/runtime/application.log`  file.
Because of many logs i use, application.log file fill so quick , and , as i see , Yii or server change that file to application.log.1 and creates a new file called `application.log` .

My Question is , why, when new `application.log` file is created , Owner and Group are like some user `nobody`, and , when the new file is created, my code such as logging doesn't work anymore , no good permissions for writing into file as `www-data` user. Are there any chances to create new `application.log` file as user different as `NOBODY`?

> I will provide Image , and look closer to `application.log.3`
>   ownership, same is happening with `application.log` , but i've changed
>   the permissions by command

Image: [image: 1]

Anyone Please Help me about this.

Comment: log file created by php. What user/group runs php on your server?

Comment: `www-data` -user runs php on my server , but , somehow , when new `application.log` log file is created , is created by `nobody` user. In logs i am getting this:
`Yii::log("User that executes script: ".exec('whoami'), "info");`

result is::
`2015/10/29 04:00:09 [info] [application] User that executes script: ec2-user`

Comment: `ec2-user`  -user runs php on my server , i was wrong

Comment: @BoJev please see answer below, hope it will help to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see `CFileLogRoute.php` class, a private variable `$_maxFileSize` is defined as `1024KB`.
when ever the size of .log file exceeds beyond this limit, this class will rotate the log files by creating new log file.

For more explanation please refer http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFileLogRoute